# Graphviz installation does not work (dll errors)

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, graphviz

I'd like to use Graphviz from http://graphviz.org. My system is Windows 7 Professional, 64bit, SP 1.

After standard installation I get the following error message **twice** when invoking dot.exe:

Title: `dot.exe - System Error`

Text: `The program can't start because graph.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.`

Invoking `dot -V` shows the version (`dot - graphviz version 2.30.0 (20130114.0323)`) after the two error messages in the console.

After the first message, the console shows `Warning: Could not load "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.30\bin\gvplugin_pango.dll" - can't open the module`. This message is repeated after the second popup error message.

This also happens with the current development snapshot version. Setting the path environment variable to include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.30\bin" does not help. Running `msiconfig /a graphviz-2.30.msi` results in a permission error. Running `msiconfig /a graphviz-2.30.msi` from an Administrator command prompt succeeds, but the problem described above persists.

Upgrading .net to 4.5 did not help.

Thanks a lot,
Carsten

Comment: I reported this to the devel mailing list (http://lists.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-devel/2013/001599.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows downloads now only show version 2.28, not 2.30. As mentioned in the comments, 2.28 installs just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same error, was able to install v2.28 after uninstalling 2.30 and it worked: http://www.graphviz.org/pub/graphviz/stable/windows/graphviz-2.28.0.msi

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry of that too, I used to install 2.28 that was working fine on Windows XP.

I have same problem with 2.30 on XP, that was corrected partially when I copied cgraph.dll to graph.dll in install repository. (as a result I have now syntax error, that I hadn't before).

That's a temporary solution, we must alert development team.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with graphviz v2.3 and v3.0 (dot.exe).

I tried **v2.0** and it worked. I advise everyone who had a problem to try it.